# What is the closest to the reverse of the Elvis operator in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

So I can replace the old ternary operation:

```
def something = mainThing != null ? mainThing : "gone!"
```

with the Elvis operator:

```
def something = mainThing ?: "gone!"
```

but is there a groovy way to replace the reverse of that:

```
def keyValuePair = (mainThing != null ? mainThing + "." : "") + "specific=" + value
```

where I'm using a prefix plus a dot if the prefix exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `?.` [safe navigation operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator) to simplify that expression. The operator currently being used (`+`) makes this hardly relevant, but assuming a method access (which also happens to be more common), you can type:

```
def keyValuePair = mainThing?.concat('.') ?: "" + "specific=" + value
```

That uses `.concat` instead of `+` for string concatenation [you can use `.plus()` :-)], and then uses `?:`. `mainThing?.concat('.')` returns null if `mainThing` is falsey (by Groovy truth terms), or the result of the method call if it is not.

Comment: Ah, of course. I was fixated on using one operator 8(

Comment: Should be noted that `def something = mainThing ?: "gone!"` will return `gone!` if `mainThing` is null, *or the empty string*.